# Let V be the plane with equation...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the plane with equation $x_1 - 4 x_2 - 2 x_3 =0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Find the matrix $A$ of the linear transformation 
$T(x)= \begin{bmatrix} 4& 2 & -8 \\ 2 & 1& -1 \\ -2& -1& -2\end{bmatrix} x$ with respect to the basis $\{\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\}$

Note: $T(x)$ is a 3x3 matrix and the basis are 3x1 matrices

Answer (score 1):

1. Figure out how $T$ acts on the basis vectors $v_1 = (4,1,0)$ and $v_2 = (2,0,1)$.
2. The vector $T(v_1)$ should be a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$. Find $a$ and $b$ with $T(v_1) = av_1 + bv_2$.
3. Similarly, write $T(v_2) = cv_1 + dv_2$.
4. The matrix $A$ is:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & c \\ b & d \end{array}\right)$$

Edit: corrected order of variables in matrix

Answer (score -1):

Let $V$ be the plane with equation $x_1 - 4 x_2 - 2 x_3 =0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Find the matrix $A$ of the linear transformation 
$T(x)= \begin{bmatrix} 4& 2 & -8 \\ 2 & 1& -1 \\ -2& -1& -2\end{bmatrix} x$ with respect to the basis $\{\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\}$

Note: $T(x)$ is a 3x3 matrix and the basis are 3x1 matrices

Comment: I do not have edit priviledge so i'm posting it here.